# How to copy file frome google drive with apache camel + java DSL?

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

Every-one I'm newly for apache camel and I want to copy file from Gdrive in my local system.That would be great for me if anyone tell me the way.

I did:

1.Maven Dependencies

```
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version> 


        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-google-drive</artifactId>
        <version>2.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

What are the dependency I need to add?

2.And for Main class/RouteBuilder class what are the packages I need     to import.
(This code I got from @Tolik Thanks4This.)

```
public class FileCopyGDrive
  {
 public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception 
   {       
 CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();  

 GoogleDriveConfiguration configuration = new GoogleDriveConfiguration();
    configuration.setApplicationName("CopyFile");
    configuration.setClientId("..");
    configuration.setClientSecret("..");
    configuration.setScopes(scopes);
    configuration.setAccessToken("..");
    configuration.setRefreshToken("..");

    GoogleDriveComponent googleDriveComponent = new GoogleDriveComponent();
    googleDriveComponent.setConfiguration(configuration);
    context.addComponent("google-drive", googleDriveComponent);

    context.addRoutes(  
         new RouteBuilder()  
         {  
            @Override  
            public void configure() throws Exception  
            {  
                from("google-drive://drive-files/copy?   ").to("file:/home/rajat/Desktop/folder");   
            }  
         });  
      context.start();  
      Thread.sleep(10000);  
      context.stop();  
     }}
  }
```

Please guys help me.

Comment: Try to work on this a bit yourself first. Your Java editor can help you with finding out which java packages to import when you copy code into the editor. And yeah you just need camel-core and the camel-google-drive component as maven dependencies.

Comment: Thank You for your supporting Ans.!!!

Comment: But here I want to insure that what I declare in my route "from() " method that is acceptable syntax for copying file.